# CSS 960 grid system layout issue

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I've been trying for ages using class="grid_x alpha omega clear etc... but no matter what I've tried I cannot get the login box @ http://ci2.totalshopuk.com/login to line up correctly. Anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `.blockheader { padding: 2px; }` to `.blockheader { padding: 1px; }`
That worked for me!

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks, there is still something that is making the white space on the left larger than right any ideas on that as well? cheers

Comment: Add a width to the .blockheader and .blockbody of 548px

Comment: Actually that would screw all the other headers etc up, add in a style .grid_14 .blockheader, .grid_14 .blockerbody { width:548px; }

Comment: It's looking perfect now by setting the width, many thanks, but I can't help but wonder why does the grid system not work for my design is there something set somewhere that is pushing the divs a few pixels that you can see?

Comment: The blockheader and blockbody classes... did you make those? or are they part of 960GS?

Comment: I made them, I guess it's the padding and borders :( ?

Comment: Yeah if you add padding then remember to take away the overall amount of padding from the width! So in your case you have 1px padding to each side, totalling to 2px extra to the width.

Answer (score 0):

Both these elements are centred in the div. You need to put the label into a  or  tag in order to control its position inside the parent div. Then set the widths accordingly to line it up.

The grid system is not always the best option for setting widths on form elements.